# Convergence and absolute convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\cos\sqrt{n+1}-\cos\sqrt{n}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\cos\sqrt{n+1}-\cos\sqrt{n}}{n}.$$
For absolute convergence I've tried using formula for difference of cosines and then wanted to use comparison test, but don't really know how to estimate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{-2\sin(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{2})\sin(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{2})}{n}\right|.$$

Comment: Simply use $$|\sin((\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})/2)|\leqslant(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})/2$$ and $$|\sin((\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})/2)|\leqslant1$$

Comment: I should have thought of that, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Did Would you mind posting this as an answer (or, if you don't have time, I can do so in Community Wiki, mentioned whence it comes)? Just to avoid losing this question -- while not hard, it's still not entirely trivial, and probably better in terms of trickiness than quite a few questions on the website.

Comment: @ClementC. Please proceed (thanks in advance).

Comment: @Did Done! ${}{}$

Comment: @ClementC. Dutifully upvoted. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is expanding on [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did)'s outline, from the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053705/test-the-following-series-for-convergence-and-absolute-convergence?noredirect=1#comment4215511_2053705).*

---

Starting from where you left, we wish to bound
$$
a_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\left\lvert \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{2}\right)}{n}\right\rvert
$$
Using the facts that

1. $\left\lvert \sin\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{2}\right\rvert \leq 1$
   and
2. $\left\lvert \sin\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{2}\right\rvert \leq \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{2}$ (from $\left\lvert\sin x\right\rvert \leq \left\lvert x\right\rvert$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$)

we get
$$
0\leq a_n \leq \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}
$$
and it only remains to conclude by comparison with a $p$-series, recalling that (for instance) $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: @ Did @ClementC. According to the answer at the end of the workbook, this series is only conditionally convergent. Do you think it's their mistake or that we are wrong? It seemed to me that your solution was right.

Comment: I'd bet on theirs -- do you have the reference of the textbook? (I can check later to make sure, if you want.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't even own the book or know the author. I just know their answer. However, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I've just checked again -- the series *is* absolutely convergent, the argument above is correct.

Comment: What @ClementC. said. And the remark that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\cos\sqrt{n+1}-\cos\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$$ is conditionally convergent, not absolutely convergent, if ever there was a typo in the question.

Answer (score 3):

By MVT

$$|\cos(\sqrt{n+1})-\cos(\sqrt{n})|$$

$$=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})|-\sin(c_n)|$$

$$\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

$$\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

$$\implies |u_n|\leq \frac{1}{2n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

$\implies \sum u_n$ absolutly convergent.$(\frac{3}{2}>1)$.